# convert deserialized java object to JSON

Tags: java, json, base64, decode, encode

I deserialized a serialized string using java 8 base64 decoder and obtained a java object as shown below. How do i convert it to JSON to send it to a SQS?

```
[payload: rO0zI2, messageHeader: {DOMAIN=prod, RequestID=aeb47c6f-104c-4d08-aab5-4a64efcf4491-20210521091053, PAYEE_CODE=AVEAJ, LEGAL_ENTITY_ID=GB, IS_TEST_INVOICE=0, QUEUE_MANAGER_TASK_ID=fincron-29dd5c7b-94f4-4559-9be3-a1cd17548144, REALM=EUAmazon, DIWS_WORKFLOW_STATE_ID=11797958482, PO_NUMBER=29JMMA6O, S3_LINK=in_jedi/GB/AVEAJ.202105210910.GB-I21015326.INV.PROCUREMENT, TASK_TYPE=EDI_INVOICE_CREATION, VENDOR_INVOICE_NUMBER=I21015326}, receiptHandle: null, sqsMessageId: null]
```

Comment: Read about [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson), it is a library which allows you to annotate your classes and serialize (from Java Object to JSON) - deserialize (vice versa) very easily.

Comment: thankyou but it is not working..it is returning the same object :(

Comment: What is not working? You should show the code you wrote or it's hard to help you